# AppleScript: Compare references in a list

Tags: list, comparison, applescript, compare, boolean

How do I make this output true and not false:

```
{item 1 of {4}, item 1 of {5}} = {4, 5}
```

I know you can do this...

```
{4, 5} = {4, 5}
```

...but I need to do something more complex.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably has to do with the binding of the `=` operator, e.g. it gets evaluated before the lhs and rhs expressions are evaluated.

For example, this is `true`:

```
set x to {item 1 of {4}, item 1 of {5}}
x = {4, 5}
```

Answer (score 2):

nmok i got it

```
set c to {item 1 of {4}, item 1 of {5}}
c is equal to {4, 5}
```

Comment: looks like samplebias beat me too it